# How replace disks on an existing striped zpool?

Tags: solaris, storage, zfs

I have the following zpool:

```
pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME                     STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        mypool                   ONLINE       0     0     0
          c9t50060E801331FC42d6  ONLINE       0     0     0
          c9t50060E801331FC42d7  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

What I need to do is to replace those disks from other of another storage, and, of course, with no downtime expected.

What I thought is to create a mirror of the striped pool and then split it, but it seems to does not work:

```
zpool add -n mypool mirror c6t500507630A200568d4 c6t500507630A200568d5
vdev verification failed: use -f to override the following errors:
mismatched replication level: pool uses disk and new vdev is mirror
Unable to build pool from specified devices: invalid vdev configuration
```

Any advice is very welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way.  Your best bet is to use snapshots to replicate the data - and do a last, hopefully-small incremental snapshot to get the last of the changes after you unmount the pool to limit your downtime, then mount the new pool.  Unless your LUNs are RAID arrays from a storage array, striping with no redundancy isn't a very good way to provide storage that can't have any downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
zpool replace mypool c9t50060E801331FC42d6 c6t500507630A200568d4
```

did the trick

Comment: One thing you really *really* need to be aware of is that if you're replacing devices in a pool which was created with 'ashift=9' [ie, it was using devices of less than 2Tb], then your new devices must also be less than 2Tb in size. If you are wanting to increase the size of your pool using 2Tb+, you will save yourself a lot of pain by creating a new pool and using snapshot, send and recv from the old to the new. Please see https://www.jmcpdotcom.com/blog/2014/12/21/help-non-aligned-writes-are-killing-my-zpool/ for what you might come up against.